# Checking number of zeros in a MIPS array

Tags: arrays, mips, mips32, sll

I have a question as follows:

*Given an array of 32-bit signed integers in the memory and its length in one of the registers, write a MIPS program that counts how many zeros the array contains. Assume that the array starts at Ox12345678, and the length of the array is already stored in $1. The number of zeros should be stored in $2, which mayor may not be initialised with zero at the beginning. Refer to Table 1 for MIPS assembly instructions.*

Here is where I have got to in my own head but I have one main question:

1) I think that if I have subroutines, I need to be pushing and then popping data from a stack by using `sw $ra, 4($sp)` and `addi $sp,$sp,-8`and `sw $fp, 0($sp)`. However, using my program, I have a break clause which only moves to a subroutine on a condition (if something is $0). So I don't `jal` to the subroutine, I `beq` to the subroutine. How can I modify my code to do this?

Here is my current code:

```
Add $3, $0, $0 #Set a counter to 0, the start of the array
Lui $4, 0x1234
Ori $4, $4, 0x5678  #Store register $4 to start of the array so you can offset
Add $2, $0, $0 #Sets $2 to $0 which is the total number of zeros

Start_for:  Beq $3, $1, end_for #If counter is equal to the array length, go to end
            Lw $5, 0x0($4) Load the current value of array into temp register $5
            Addi $4, $4, 4 #Increment array pointer to next value
            Beq $5, $0, increment #Increment the sum by 1 if the array[i] is zero
            Addi $3, $3, 1 #Increment counter by 1
            J start_for     
increment:
            Addi $2, $2, 1 #Increment the number of zeros by 1 and add to sum
            Jr $ra
End_for:    Lui $8, 0xffff
            Ori $8, $8, 0xf004 Load the outtray into $8
            Lw $8, 0x0($2) Store the number of zeros in the array to the outtray
```

Comment: You are attempting to count the number of zero bits in all of the integers in the array. The assignment seems to be asking you to count the number of integers that are zero in the array of integers: e.g. array '1,3,0,9,0' has two zeros.

Comment: Oh gosh you are right. Let me adjust my current answer.

Comment: It this a thought experiment or do you get to use a real assembler? Are you sure about `$1` as the register? That's the `$at` ["assember temporary"] register. So, if you use _any_ instructions that are actually pseudo-ops that generate a multiple instruction sequence, the assembler assumes it can do what it wishes with the value in `$1/$at`. You _can_ do it, but you need to use _extra_ care by avoiding [certain] pseudo-ops or moving the value to a different reg (e.g. `addu $10,$1,$0` and use `$10` instead)

Comment: I don't think it matters for this question but I take your point you should be using actual MIPS registers e.g. $v, $s, $t etc.